# Problem with WCF Hosting on Mono

Tags: wcf, mono, mod-mono

I am trying to host a simple application with one .aspx, .asmx and .svc file each. I followed the below guide to achieve the hosting (since I am very new to the linux world, it took a while to understand it!):

http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Manual_Mod_Mono_Configuration

After all the hosting, I am able to access the aspx and asmx file. But when I try to access the svc file, I get the below error:

***The ServiceHost must have at least one application endpoint (that does not include metadata exchange endpoint) defined by either configuration, behaviors or call to AddServiceEndpoint methods.***

or

***HttpListenerContext does not match any of the registered channels***

I do have a pretty straight forward service endpoint defined in my web.config which looks like below:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TestWCFService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/MonoTest/TestWCFService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="MonoTest.ITestWCFService"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Note: I used MS VS 2010 to create this project and then published it. The published directory is copied to the Apache/Linux Environment. The WCF doesn't make use of any complex type. I am using Mono Version 2.8.2

**UPDATE**
Update: I tried using 2.10.2 Mono. This error is gone and I am now facing a new one:

```
XmlSchema error: Named item http://tempuri.org/:DoWork was already contained in the schema object table. Consider setting MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT to 'yes' to mimic MS implementation. Related schema item SourceUri: , Line 0, Position 0.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After weeks of R&D on this I have figured out this. For some reason, I can't get the service WSDL to work (meaning I can't access the .svc from browser). However, the service works fine when I try to access it using Channel Factory.

So I have implemented everything in Channel Factory (for my Silverlight app) and everything seems to be working fine right now. I am still not sure how to get WSDL to work but that's not too important to me as of now.